# Appropriate Stout Style for Chicory, Coffee (and more!)

Tags: stout, chocolate, coffee

In Radical Brewing, Randy Mosher has a great section on 10 ways to improve stout brewing (including home-roasting flaked oats/funky grains). I plan on employing several of these techniques, including ~5% acidulated malt, into a big, bold stout I am brewing for my brother's 50th. He and I have had some great times in New Orleans, including my own bachelor party, and he's a huge fan of the chicory coffee.

I was thinking of basing the style on Jamil's American Stout, as my brother is also a hophead, but am concerned that this is going to be one of those 'kitchen sink' recipes that ends up being a jumbled mess.

13 lbs American 2 row 
1 lb acid malt 
1 lb Roasted Barley 
.75lb Chocolate Malt 
.75lb crystal 40 
.5 lb toasted flaked oats 
1 lb toasted buckwheat 
horizon 1.4 oz 60 minute 
Centennial a oz 5 minute 
US-05 @ 67 degrees 
Secondary with cold-steeped coffee, chicory, cocoa nibs (not sure on amounts) 
target OG will be mid-70's.

I guess real simply, my question is: what style stout are the popular coffee-ish stouts, such as Founder's Breakfast Stout, DFH Chicory Stout and will the American hops kill the goodness from the adjuncts? I know this question is somewhat subjective, but I would like to draw on people's experience.

Answer (score 1):

If your brother is a hop head what about doing a Cascadian dark ale (http://www.byo.com/stories/beer-styles/article/indices/11-beer-styles/2072-birth-of-a-new-style-cascadian-dark-ale) like Deschutes Hop in the Dark.  I bet that would pair well with your chicory coffee.  That way you get the best of all worlds, and the dark and roasted malt wouldn't overwhelm the hops or chicory coffee.

Comment: I do loooooove Cascadian Dark Black India Black Pale Ales, but I was thinking of going more in a hoppy american stout direction.  Similar to Sixpoint's Diesel Stout (www.ratebeer.com/beer/sixpoint-diesel-stout/47131/).  Just trying to see if some of the adjuncts would work with the hop profiles.

Comment: Never had Sixpoint's Diesel Stout, but I bet you could darken up a CDA a bit and add a bit more body (either by mashing at a higher temp or adding some oatmeal).  Reveiwers of the Sixpoint's Diesel said it had a pine taste which could be emulated with Sounds like the Sixpoint's Diesel has some Chinook or Simcoe hops.

Comment: http://hopville.com/recipe/1069973/american-stout-recipes/sixpoint-diesel-stout-clone

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Horizon, but [reviews](http://www.brew365.com/hops_horizon.php) show that it's not a citrus bomb, but on the whole neutral and clean, with some earthiness and spiciness. To my mind, those qualities are good with stouts.

For the aroma addition, I would probably go with Wiliamette or similar hop (Ultra, Tettanger, Hallertau, Crystal, although that's a bit pungent) - Centennial is very citrus - would you put lemon juice in your coffee? Well, some people do, but it's an unusual drink and not to everyone's taste.

Comment: Upvote, good call on the citrus.  Tried doing a Sorachi Ace IBA, and its good, not great.  The lemony-ness of the Sorachi's doesn't quite work with the roast.  roast+citrus = bleh; roast+earth = yes.

Comment: agree about roast+citrus=bleh, nicely put! Sounds like a good brew - inspired me to go out and get some chocolate nibs and some chicory.